# In Rails, how would you create a DB entry asynchronously using fetch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, fetch-api, crud

**What I want to achieve**

When the user clicks on the thumbs up, in the database join table `likes(user_id, project_id)`, an entry is created to reflect the users upvote on the project. The count is updated unless the user has already upvoted the project before.

I was hoping a simple JS fetch request would do. Unfortunately, it results in a 500 error.

`home.html.erb`

```html
<div class="card" data-project-id='1'>
...
   <span class="tag upvotes"> 143</span>
...
</div>
```

`application.js`

```js
...
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
...

  const upvote = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.tag.upvotes').forEach((tag) => {
      tag.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const project_id = e.target.closest('.card').dataset.projectId;
        fetch(`projects/${project_id}/like/`, {
          method: 'post'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  upvote();

});
```

`routes.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  post 'projects/:id/like', to: 'projects#like'
end
```

`projects_controller.rb`

```rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def like
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @like = Like.create(user: current_user, project: @project) unless Like.where(user: current_user, project: @project)
    render json: Like.where(project: @project).count.to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you try "fetch(`/projects/${project_id}/like/`" ... With an extra slash before the projects on the fetch?

Comment: Hi jad, the issue seems to lie with the line starting with `render ...`. How would I return a simple string (in the controller) and how would I handle it with fetch (in the JS file)?

Comment: What output do you get by calling the URL directly in the browser? (Can you add it to the question?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your JSON response would return an error. You're basically writing something like this `2.to_json`
Create a proper JSON like:

```
{ number_of_linkes: Like.where(project: @project).count }.to_json
```

then in the JS code write `data.number_of_likes`